# Can't set up entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework, f#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set up a db context in a .net core F# web app. As part of this I need to convert the following in to F#:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

My F# version is:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(fun (options: DbContextOptionsBuilder) ->
            options.UseSqlite(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
```

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
No overloads match for method 'AddDbContext'. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window).property Startup.Configuration: IConfigurationRoot
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I hadn't added a constructor for ApplicationDbContext that takes a DbContextOptions as a parameter. After changing the default constructor to

```
type ApplicationDbContext(options: DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>) = 
      inherit IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>(options)
```

I could compile

Answer (score 0):

`UseSqlite` return `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder` value, so you need ignore it to match `Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>`.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(fun (options: DbContextOptionsBuilder) ->
            options.UseSqlite(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")) |> ignore)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to explain how this will help solve OP's problem. Thank you!